# HSQLDB properties that the documentation doesn't mention

Tags: hsqldb, rdbms

In `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES` there are these 3 entries that I can't find anything on in the docs:

```
hsqldb.min_reuse
sql.compare_in_locale
textdb.lvs
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are among the properties that can be used in the connection URL when a new HSQLDB database is created.

The `textdb.lvs` property is a legacy property from version 1.8 and has no effect in recent versions.

The `sql.compare_in_locale=true` property setting uses the language of the Java runtime Locale as the default collation.

The `hsqldb.min_reuse` setting can be used to specify the smallest row space that is recovered and reused immediately when the row is deleted from a CACHED table. This property can be used in conjunction with the Table Space feature. With a large value such as `hsqldb.min_reuse=4096`, the deleted spaces are not immediately reused but when they add up and a whole block becomes free, the block as a whole is reused.